# Pytest + ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project_name.settings'

Tags: python, scrapy, pytest, setup.py

I'm trying to test a scrapy spider using pytest. I'd like to make sure that a certain spider say, X, has been generated with that specific name. I can acess scrapy spiders from a script using the following code fragment:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
spiders =  list(process.spiders._spiders.keys())
```

However, when I'm trying to run this very same code fragment in pytest I get an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project_name.settings'
```

My project directory is as follows.

```
**project_name**
├── __init__.py
├── scrapy.cfg
├── setup.py
├── **project_name**
│   ├── cli
│   ├── conftest.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── settings.py
    ├── spiders
    ├── tests
       ├── unit
```

I think the problem comes from the way I created my pip package because scrapy's `get_project_settings()` is requesting for the `project_name.settings` module that has been "remapped" in setup.py from  `project_name.project_name.settings` but pytest does not know where to find that `project_name.settings`. It can see it if it's `project_name.project_name.settings` but not otherwise. This is my setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools import find_packages

setup(
    name='project_name',
    description='',
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
)
```

Now, I don't know how to get pytest to understand that `project_name.settings` actually means `project_name.project_name.settings` using, I guess, setup.py or pytest plugins. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Does the subfolder have to have the same name? Regardless, it can't find a module by that name, because it doesn't exist. You need to make the *project_name* subdirectory a module by adding a blank **init**.py file in there. You might also need to specify a relative path from inside settings or a full path. So either `.project_name` or `project_name.project_name`. Hope this helps.

Comment: my bad. There was a blank  __init__.py under `project_name.project_name`

Comment: Ah, okay. Well did the change in pathing help you out?

Comment: No, it did not.